# Reduce spacing between two (custom) paragraphs in scrreprt

Tags: spacing, koma-script, paragraphs

I have defined a custom paragraph named `myparagraph` to use it as a small, unnumbered headline within my document. The reason is that I like the font of the `paragraph` heading, which is not as bold as compared to `\textbf{}`.

Now I have just realized that each new use of `myparagraph` leaves a little bit too much vertical space, see the following picture with the gap in red:

[image]

I need to control this gap, either globally, or locally between these two `myparagraphs` (maybe use half the value which is used now, or something close, in order to save space) by redefining `myparagraph` somehow.

edit: If you got a different solution feel free to post it. It doesn't strictly have to be a redefinition of `paragraph`.

edit2: The headlines should not be part of the TOC. They are supposed to be very simple headlines on the lowest level so to say, nothing more.

The code is quite simple:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline, headings=small,]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}

\newcommand{\myparagraph}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\[3pt]}

\begin{document}

\myparagraph{Test}
\Blindtext[1][1]
\myparagraph{Test}
\Blindtext[1][1]
\textbf{}
\end{document}
```

error log:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \subparagraphnumdepth
```

Comment: Since you are using a KOMA-Script class: Why don’t you apply the specific macro `\minisec`? (Without testing: It may be though, the gap would be still too big for you.)

Comment: @Speravir thanks for the hint. I tried it and the font seems to be the same as in `paragraph` which is good. The distance is also smaller which is even better. However I'd really like to set the distance to specific values, which might differ between cases.

Comment: Sans serif fonts are the default for every title level in KOMA-Script. What I’ve forgotten to mention: Minisecs aren’t by default thought to be listed in the table of contents (could be overruled with `\addtocontents` or `\addcontentsline`).

Comment: @Speravir That's fine in my case as I don't want these headlines to be in the TOC :) They are supposed to be simple headlines on the lowest level. I will edit this in the description.

Comment: @TomM Update your Koma-Script suite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with `\minisec`, a specific KOMA-Script command, that probably suites better here for the assumed usage:

```
\documentclass[12pt, headsepline, headings=small,]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% another package for dummy text

\let\OrigMinisec\minisec
\renewcommand{\minisec}[2][0pt]{\vspace{#1}\OrigMinisec{#2}}

\begin{document}

\kant[1]
\minisec{Minisection 1}
\kant[2]
\minisec[-1ex]{Minisection 2}
\kant[3]
\minisec[-0.75\baselineskip]{Minisection 3}
\kant[4]
\minisec[2ex]{Minisection 4}
\kant[5]
\end{document}
```

According to the definition in the class by default *(i.e. when you leave out the optional argument of the redefined version)* a vertical skip of 1.5ex is added above minisections.

Answer (score 3):

Just redefine `\paragraph to do what you want.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline, headings=small,]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{%
  \@startsection{paragraph}{\paragraphnumdepth}%
  {\z@}% title indentation
  {-3pt \@plus -1pt \@minus -1pt }% negative values suppress indent on next paragraph
  {3pt \@plus 1pt \@minus 1pt }% positive value makes a line break after the title
  {\raggedsection\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@paragraph}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Test}
\Blindtext[1][1]
\paragraph{Test}
\Blindtext[1][1]
\textbf{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to keep `\paragraph`, redefine `\subparagraph`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline, headings=small,]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}{%
  \@startsection{subparagraph}{\subparagraphnumdepth}%
  {\z@}% title indentation
  {-3pt \@plus -1pt \@minus -1pt }% negative values suppress indent on next paragraph
  {3pt \@plus 1pt \@minus 1pt }% positive value makes a line break after the title
  {\raggedsection\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@paragraph}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\subparagraph{Test}
\Blindtext[1][1]
\subparagraph{Test}
\Blindtext[1][1]
\textbf{}
\end{document}
```

The output is just the same as before.

Comment: hmm I would like to keep `paragraph` the way it is, if possible, but to change only `myparagraph` instead. Can I simple replace `\renewcommand{\paragraph}{%` with `\renewcommand{\myparagraph}{%` Edit: No that doesn't work because of the definition of `myparagraph`

Comment: But thanks for your entry egreg. It's also good to know how to redefine paragraph globally

Comment: @TomM Do you plan to use `\subparagraph`?

Comment: Nope I haven't used that

Comment: @TomM Then redefine `\subparagraph`! Just add `sub` everywhere.

Comment: I'll try that too, thanks! Edit: didn't work. I added sub in front of every paragraph - `Missing number/Undef contr sequence`

Comment: I have also tried your solution again and it always throws the mentioned errors. Is that just me?

Comment: @TomM I added the code.

Comment: hmm if I run this code I am still getting `The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., \hobx), type I and the correct
spelling (e.g., I\hbox). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.` Also `! Missing number, treated as zero.` Did you test this code?

Comment: @TomM With my example? *What* control sequence is undefined?

Comment: yes with your example, nothing changed. I edited the error log to the question.